# Ursina engine misses collisions

Tags: python, collision-detection, collision, ursina

I have the following code, which checks essentially when a line collides with a cube.

For some reason, not all collisions are detected. I created a short example with some lines with the following color coding:

if no hit: cyan

1 hit: brown

2: red

3: orange

4: gold

5: black (though there are only 4 targets, you shouldn't see this)

As you could see, 3 lines cross all the 4 targets but are represented by cyan color.
[image]
[image]

The example to run:

```
from ursina import *
import numpy as np

# USEFUL VARIABLES
SCINTILLATOR_SIZE_X = 0.5
SCINTILLATOR_SIZE_Y = 0.5
SCINTILLATOR_SIZE_Z = 0.0254  # 1 inch

objects = []
VEC0_3D = Vec3(0, 0, 0)


# USEFUL FUNCTIONS
def draw_wireframe_cube(pos, size, color):
    cube = Entity(model='wireframe_cube', world_position=pos, scale=size, color=color, mode='line')
    return cube


def size_of_vec(vec):
    """
    Returns the size of a given vector
    :param vec: 3D vector
    :return: Size of 3D vector "vec"
    """
    return np.sqrt((vec.x ** 2 + vec.y ** 2 + vec.z ** 2))


def check_muons_collisions(muons):
    hit_entities = []
    for muon in muons:
        hit_entities.append(muon.calculate_collisions())
    return hit_entities


# SCINTILLATOR (IS A CUBOID) CLASS
class Scintillator(Entity):
    def __init__(self, level, pos, size, rotation, mesh_wire):
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size
        self.rotation = rotation
        self.mesh_wire = mesh_wire
        Entity.__init__(self, scale=size, position=pos, model='cube', collider='box', color=color.pink)


# CREATE SCINTILLATOR METHOD
def create_scintillator(num_of_scints):
    """
    This function will create the main scintillator 
    :return: Returns the scintillator object
    """""
    scintillator_ref = [x for x in objects if isinstance(Scintillator, x)]
    if len(scintillator_ref) > 0:
        print("A scintillator is already defined!")
        return
    scint_size = Vec3(SCINTILLATOR_SIZE_X, SCINTILLATOR_SIZE_Y, SCINTILLATOR_SIZE_Z)  # set in settings
    scint_rot = VEC0_3D  # in degrees
    for i in range(num_of_scints):
        scint_pos = Vec3(0, 0, -num_of_scints / 2 + 0.5) * 0.1 + Vec3(0, 0, 1) * 0.1 * i  # in meters
        wireframe = draw_wireframe_cube(scint_pos, scint_size * 1.01, color=color.black)
        scint = Scintillator(i, scint_pos, scint_size, scint_rot, wireframe)
        wireframe.collider = None
        wireframe.parent = scint
    objects.insert(-1, scint)  # TODO: understand if scintillator's size is from middle point or some edge point
    return scint


# MUON (IS A LINE) CLASS
class Muon(Entity):
    """
    Object class for muons
    """

    def __init__(self, index, start, end, energy):
        """
        Initialization function for a muon
        :param start: Starting point
        :param end: End point
        :param energy: Energy, used for calculating scintillation.
        :param mesh: Mesh reference.
        """
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        # self.momentum = momentum
        self.energy = energy
        #self.mesh_ref = mesh
        self.index = index
        self.hit_info = None
        Entity.__init__(self, model=Mesh(vertices=[start, end], mode='line', thickness=0.1), color=color.green)

    def calculate_collisions(self):  # TODO: print only hit ground
        self.hit_info = raycast(self.start, self.end - self.start,
                                distance=size_of_vec(self.start - self.end), debug=True)
        entities = self.hit_info.entities
        x = len(entities)
        if x == 0:
            self.color = color.cyan
        if x == 1:
            self.color = color.brown
        if x == 2:
            self.color = color.red
        if x == 3:
            self.color = color.orange
        if x == 4:
            self.color = color.gold
        if x == 5:
            self.color = color.black
        for entity in entities:
            print(type(entity))
            print(entity.name)
            if isinstance(entity, Scintillator):
                self.print_collision(entity, self.hit_info.point)
        return entities

    def print_collision(self, entity, position):
        print("*************************")
        print("Muon " + str(self.index) + " hit " + str(entity) + " at " + str(position))
        print("*************************")


def create_n_random_muons(n):
    """
    This function will create and print n muons of varying energies and angels
    :param n: Number of muons
    :return: Array of all muons
    """

    muons = []  # This hold the new n muons
    # This holds calculated start points. I calculated some random ones for you
    start_points = [Vec3(-142.749, -219.022, 999.763),
                    Vec3(-143.519, 108.823, 999.763),
                    Vec3(-393.619, -104.295, 999.763),
                    Vec3(1212.26, 570.423, 999.763),
                    Vec3(-51.1669, 35.664, 999.763),
                    Vec3(323.465, -27.7195, 999.763),
                    Vec3(245.713, 183.488, 999.763),
                    Vec3(363.892, 647.235, 999.763),
                    Vec3(201.392, 574.155, 999.763),
                    Vec3(-253.416, -743.39, 999.763),
                    Vec3(171.414, 198.996, 999.763),
                    Vec3(-11.5856, 12.0816, 999.763),
                    Vec3(-46.2548, 257.973, 999.763),
                    Vec3(761.947, -622.162, 999.763),
                    Vec3(-496.811, -295.885, 999.763)]

    # This holds calculated end points. I calculated some for you
    end_points = [Vec3(-0.00927782, -0.0904079, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(-0.149831, -0.241173, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(-0.0478061, 0.051418, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(0.17725, -0.0356445, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(0.217475, -0.225569, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(0.188968, -0.064771, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(-0.19695, -0.0399446, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(-0.154698, -0.141071, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(0.0940816, -0.133347, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(0.144424, 0.223723, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(-0.161474, 0.0230457, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(-0.0304296, -0.152948, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(-0.00892861, 0.0107271, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(0.138, -0.196602, -0.2373),
                  Vec3(-0.216395, -0.0713366, -0.2373)
                  ]  # This holds randomized end points

    # For loop to create n muons
    for i in range(0, n):  # Create n end vectors for Muons

        muon_i = Muon(i, start_points[i], end_points[i], 1)
        objects.append(muon_i)
        muons.append(muon_i)
    return muons


def main(argv):
    app = Ursina(title='example')

    # Create XYZ axes

    scints = create_scintillator(4)  # NUMBER_OF_SCINTS = 4

    muons = create_n_random_muons(10)

    check_muons_collisions(muons)
    # cntrl.create_ground(10, Vec3(1, 1, 0), Vec3(1, 2, 2))

    EditorCamera()  # TODO: build a better camera
    app.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `collider = 'box'` to the `__init__` function of super class of the Muon class.

Correction:

```
Entity.__init__(self, model=Mesh(vertices=[start, end], mode='line', thickness=0.1), color=color.green, collider='box')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This causes the line to have a very big collider that needs to be re-adjusted. Don't know if you can do it in ursina